# When to async'ly require modules using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, amd

I know two possible ways of loading dependencies:

1. synchronous way:

   ```
   define(['jquery'], function($) { // code });
   ```

   The callback function will be invoked **once** `jquery` is loaded.
2. asynchronous way:

   ```
   define(function(require) { 
      var $ = require('jquery'); 
      // code 
   });
   ```

   The callback will be invoked, the `require('jquery')` will be executed in the background and the thread will keep evaluating the rest of the `// code`.

My question is, if my code depends on any library, say `jquery`, how come it is okay to go with the second approach? the code will be trying to make use of `jquery` **before** it was fully loaded.

Yet, I see tons of examples with this approach, so it looks like I'm missing something.

Can you help me better understand that?

Comment: You've mixed the two up. The first one is asynchronous, the second one only works when jQuery is already loaded.

Comment: How come it "works" when jquery is already loaded? that is impossible. Once the callback function starts executing, it invokes the `require('jquery')` and keeps executing the rest of the code.

Comment: This is how it behaves in practice.. could it be right for an older version of `RequireJS`?

Comment: @johni There is no "older version" that worked differently. See my answer on the question against which this one was closed as duplicate for the explanation of how it works.